# Laravel Queue using Beanstalkd Failing

Tags: php, laravel

I've tried to using queue for everytime user register and send an email to them to verify.

I'm doing it successfully using Laravel 5.1
I just wandering how can I can stop current queue if I got an error and then when I fix it I restart the job from the last queue?.

How about the error like this:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
View [emails.versify_email] not found.



[InvalidArgumentException]
View [emails.versify_email] not found.



[InvalidArgumentException]
View [emails.versify_email] not found.
```

I've tried at homestead using:

```
 public function failed(){
    //I've tried send email but it not sending
 }
```

or at AppServiceProvider

```
Queue::failing(function ($connection, $job, $data) {
        $user ='mymail@gmail.com';
        Mail::send('emails.fail_queue', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use        ($user) {
            $m->subject('Failing:' . $user)
                ->to($user);
        });
    });
```

None of the them is working.
what should i do if its like that when happened at production?.

Comment: By "stop current queue if I got an error", do you mean stopping the current job and retrying later? Or do you mean stopping the whole queue (and all jobs in it)?

Comment: stopping the current job and retrying later. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When an exception is thrown from the handler Laravel tries to release the job back to the queue unless it is explicitly deleted.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L198-L227

You can use the $delay parameter to put back in the queue with delay. Or better just bury the job yourself, if you are able to detect the issue.

```
$this->job->bury()
```